# Variable within variable possible?

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to create a loop statement for some of my code and am wondering how I can put a variable within another variable.

### For example:

```
<?php 
$j=1;
while ($j <= 9): {

$f$jfname = $_SESSION['F$jFirstName'];
$f$jmi = $_SESSION['F$jMI'];
$f$jlname = $_SESSION['F$jLastName'];
}
 $j++; endwhile; 
?>
```

Where the goal is to have the j variable increase during the loop and change the values as:

> $f1fname $f2fname $f3fname

and so on.

Any ideas?

### EDIT

Yes I am aware that my INITIAL form was flawed in the way I captured information (as individual variables as opposed to arrays) so any answer telling me that SESSION is an array and so on is irrelevant because I cannot call any variables implicitly from the SESSION variables I created (without a line by line reference) All variable stored in SESSION are completely unique and independent of each other.

Comment: Ack. Your variable naming confuses me greatly. I'm not quite sure what you're going for... can we try a more concise code sample that, rather than being your application code, contains just the principle you're going for?

Comment: not sure why the question was confusing or why it deserved a -1? I think there are a alot of people who previously did not understand arrays would benefit

Comment: @JM4: You already **have** the solution to your problem in the code. After all `$_SESSION` is just that: a variable that includes other variables.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - it does not for the following reason: I store everything in SESSION without any variable names so in order to call the 16th person's city, I would have to write $_SESSION['F16City'] and write out tons of code which is exactly what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @JM4: That’s not what I mean. You don’t need to use `$_SESSION` (in fact you *should not*) but `$_SESSION` is essentially the same as your solution (i.e. an associative array). The same, in fact, as `$names` in the solution that you accepted below.

Comment: @Konrad - why should I 'not' use SESSION variables? I am carrying the information from page to page during an enrollment process.

Comment: @JM4: Your current usage of the SESSION variable is completely fine. You should *not* use it to solve the particular problem that triggered this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test the code myself but perhaps something like:

```
<?php 
$names = array();
for ($j=1; $j <= 9; $j++) {
   if (! isset($names[$j]))
     $names[$j] = array();
   $names[$j]['fname'] = $_SESSION["F{$j}FirstName"];
   $names[$j]['mi'] = $_SESSION["F{$j}MI"];
   $names[$j]['lname'] = $_SESSION["F{$j}LastName"];
}
?>
```

Then you have an array with arrays of the userinfo

Comment: I think this would work well but I am just so unfamiliar with how to then call on each individual variable (I am currently printing $f1fname on a PDF file by specific location and so on with over 300 variables. Not quite sure how to do this using arrays.

Comment: For example, you would print the firstname of the 2nd person with:
echo $names[2]['fname'];

Comment: Or to iterate through all names:
foreach($names as $entry) { echo $entry['fname']; }

Comment: I think this would normally work but want to run by how I'm using this. I place each variable (1st person first name) at X and Y coordinates on the page. I am unable to 'loop' the write statements because they X and Y coordinates different for every single variable so while I can change the name of the variable being input to $names[1]['fname'], I am not sure of the benefit when compared to $f1fname. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

what about arrays? more: arrays of objects?

Comment: +1: Arrays are the correct way to solve this problem.  More specifically, `$_SESSION` can store arrays just as easily as single values, so why not just set/retrieve an array from it instead?

Answer (score 1):

php wont parse variables inside single quotes ', use double quotes " and try this format...

```
${'f'.$j.'fname'} = $_SESSION["F$jFirstName"];
```

Comment: ...this is actually supported? Ew, ew, ew. +1, since it answers the original question well, but please, please, please, no one ever actually do this.

Comment: @Matchu - why do you dislike this answer? It actually accomplishes every goal I am trying to go for but am curious why it is bad practice.

Comment: Arrays are a standard way of accomplishing what you want, and you see it everywhere in the wild. This format *never, ever* appears in the wild, and for good reason: *this is what arrays are for*. As such, arrays come with all the extra goodies like free iteration and `array_search` and the like. No need to duplicate the functionality of arrays while robbing yourself of extra behavior and confusing any future developer (trust me, I'd be stumped for a good 15 minutes).

Comment: i agree, this method is ugly, arrays are a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

To references a variable given its name, you can do it as follows:

- Directly:

  ```
  $result=$myVar;
  ```
- From String:

  ```
  $result="$myVar";
  ```
- From Variable:

  ```
  $a='myVar';
  $result=$$a;
  ```

---

And your code....

```
    // preferred way
    $results=array();
    for ($j=1; $j<=9; $j++) {
        $result=array();
        $result['jfname'] = $_SESSION['f'.$j.'FirstName'];
        $result['jmi'] = $_SESSION['f'.$j.'MI'];
        $result['lname'] = $_SESSION['f'.$j.'LastName'];
        $results[$j]=$result;
    }
```

---

By the way,

```
$_SESSION['f'.$j.'LastName'];
```

Is the same as

```
$_SESSION["f{$j}LastName"];
```

Comment: thank you for your code. The overall idea is helpful but the code is a bit flawed. For example, In the result array, ['jfname'] is improper context and would result in jfname, instead of 1fname or 2fname as needed.

Comment: $results[$j]['fname'] is more "standard", since having different variable indexes isn't preferable.

It might depend on implementation, but I still believe it is the best approach rather than using indexes as the name of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you need this, but i you thought about it and realy want to do that, you just have to write

```
$varname = "f".$j."fname"; 
$$varname = ...
```

instead of

```
$f$jfname = ...
```

Comment: This seems to be what the OP wants... but I would warn you that this is generally considered to be a bad idea and can lead to painful and difficult-to-diagnose bugs.

Comment: reason i need numbered variables is because i have 30 first names (among several other variables) I want to run through. I currently have all the code listed out but the file sizes are getting huge.

Comment: Iterating through an array is much easier than iterating through numbered variables. Have you worked with arrays before? http://php.net/array

Comment: @Matchu - I only have started to. Just started trying to write code a month ago but I am using fpdf to output some of the SESSION variables. Remembering that $f1fname is the first person's first name and where it needs to go in the PDF is much easier for me to remember than array[12]

Comment: i know what arrays are, i know this is a dumb idea and i would never use this, because i know its very, very dumb - but it't the answer to the question above, so i don't understand why i get downvotes for this...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wait, I think I get it now.

How about we just have an array to contain it? Variable variables are messy enough, don't you think?

```
<?php
$f = array();
for($j = 1; $j <= 9; $j++) {
  $f[$j] = array();
  $f[$j]['fname'] = $_SESSION['F' . $j. 'FirstName'];
  // etc.
}
?>
```

Comment: I think your reasoning makes sense, i was just trying to consolidate lines of code though. I have 12 variables I want to run through the 'while' loop up top and creating the arrays you mention seems like it will take up just as many lines of code if I want to run through all the variables. Perhaps not but I can give it a shot

Comment: It's definitely easier to iterate through an array when you're done than to iterate through numbered variables - or worse, type out all of those variable names yourself :o